# Custom query filtered by custom field which is an array

Tags: custom-fields, wordpress

I have a custom field in my posts called "position" , Actually i created it with ACF checkboxes and it returns an array.Now i wanna query posts filtered by this custom field in this way that if value "x" is in the custom field then show the post. I tried this code but it doesn't work :(

```
$posts_sabet_1 = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'sabet',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'      => 'position', // array
                'value'    => 'top', // is "top" in "position" field?
                'compare'  => 'LIKE' // I also tried "IN" , "=" , "RLIKE" . none of them worked
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
$posts_sabet_1 = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'sabet',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'position'
        'meta_value' => 'top'
        )
);
```

Comment: It's the same as the code i written with "=" compare , it doesn't work